# Python List, taking one item from one to another

Tags: python, list, iteration

(newbie) I have looked for answers, however, other examples are not sufficient for what I am looking for. As the title states, I am simply trying to take one `item`, or in this case `card` , from one list to another. The two lists are called 'deck' and 'hand.'

Once you pull from one list, it goes into the other, and gets deleted from its original.

**Edit** made more specific:

```
deck = [cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, dog, bird, bird, shark, shark, shark]

hand = []
new_deck = []

def startUpCards():
        if len(deck) >= 7:
            hand = random.sample(deck, 7)
            new_deck = [item for item in deck if item not in hand]
            deck = list(new_deck)
        elif len(deck) < 7:
            hand = random.sample(deck, len(deck))
            new_deck = [item for item in deck if item not in hand]
            deck = list(new_deck)
```

So above is what you start out with, and everything comes out correct as intended. However, this is where my problem comes in, although no error occurs:

```
def addNewCard():
    if len(deck) > 0:
        hand.extend(random.sample(deck, 1))
        new_deck = [item for item in deck if item not in hand]
        deck = list(new_deck)
    else:
        sleep(2)
        print ("You don't have any more cards in your deck!")

    startUpCards()

cardChosen = input("Which card do you want to draw?")

def rmv_hand():
    hand.remove(cardChosen)
    addNewCard()
    `print(hand)`
```

The issue that I am finding is that after the first draw, `hand` is shortened by 1, possibly meaning it didn't draw from `deck`, right?

I also see that my print string `("You don't have any more cards in your deck!")` is printing waaay before I expect it to! What's going on?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your given code into a text file and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which debugger are you using to step through the code and see the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going through far too much work.  Use **randrange** to select a card by *position*.  Use **pop** to remove that element from the deck, and *immediately* append it to the receiving hand.  Here is a simple example:

```
import random

deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
hand = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

# Choose a random card from the deck *by position*
draw_pos = random.randrange(len(deck))
print "Pulling card #", draw_pos, "from deck to hand"
hand.append(deck.pop(draw_pos))
print deck 
print hand
```

Sample output:

```
Pulling card # 2 from deck to hand
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 3]
```

Does that get you going?

Comment: Why not use `shuffle`?  When manipulating actual cards, you don't randomly go through the deck and choose one, you just shuffle and continuously take them off the top.

Comment: That's a good suggestion to the OP; I avoided over-answering.  Shuffle the deck, and then you deal with **hand.append(deck.pop())**

Comment: Sorry, did not include the detail, the `hand` can only have 7 cards from deck... so how would that work?

Comment: ignore the last question. I'm going to bed. Yes, thanks, it works :)